# Remove first character of a multi-line string in a text file

Tags: ubuntu, sed, string

I'm automating the build process of Ubuntu 20.04 VMs. It seems that Ubuntu 20.04 comes with bash-completion disabled by default. I would like to enable this by default at build time. The life-cycle management system I use allows me to run some final commands before the VM boots completely built. What I need is to enable bash-completion for all users via `/etc/bash.bashrc`.

Currently, a built machine's `/etc/bash.bashrc` looks like:

```bsh
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

...

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
#if ! shopt -oq posix; then
#  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
#  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
#    . /etc/bash_completion
#  fi
#fi

...

EOF
```

I would like to remove each of the `#` characters after the line `# enable bash completion in interactive shells`. The result should be:

```bsh
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

...

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

...

EOF
```

I've tried to write up a `sed` command but am having no luck. Any ideas would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: FYI it's disabled in `/etc/bash.bashrc` because it's enabled in `/etc/skel/.bashrc` - which gets copied to users' home directories on account creation by the default adduser.conf

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
sed -i -e '/^# enable bash completion/,/^#fi/ {
             s/^#//;
             s/^ enable bash completion/#&/;
           }' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

This strips the leading `#` from all lines from the line beginning with `# enable bash completion` to the next line beginning with `#fi`, and then puts the `#` back at the start of the `enable bash ...` line.

Comment: Cheers! This worked a charm

Answer (score 1):

The following will remove all `#`s at the start of a line from the line after `# enable bash completion in interactive shells` til the last contiguous line that starts with `#`:

```
$ awk '
    f && !sub(/^#/,"") { f=0 }
    $0 == "# enable bash completion in interactive shells" { f=1 }
1' file
# System-wide .bashrc file for interactive bash(1) shells.

...

# enable bash completion in interactive shells
if ! shopt -oq posix; then
  if [ -f /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion ]; then
    . /usr/share/bash-completion/bash_completion
  elif [ -f /etc/bash_completion ]; then
    . /etc/bash_completion
  fi
fi

...

EOF
```

Comment: Dear habitual drive-by downvoter - if you have anything constructive to contribute to the forum please do let us know.

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

The following would remove `#` from start of record after fifth record.

```
awk 'NR>5{sub(/^#/,"");}1' input
```

or

```
awk 'NR==1,/^# enable/{print;next}{sub(/^#/,"");print }' input
```

`NR==1,/^# enable/{print;next}` prints from first record to record starting with `# enable`. The `next` statement means no further actions would be taken on these records.

Then `sub()` function removes `#` from start of record.

Another method:
This is in `awk` as described in [the answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/654599/469418) by @cas.

```
awk '/^# enable/,/^#fi/
{if (/^# enable/) ; else sub(/^#/,"")}1' input
```

Answer (score 0):

GNU sed

```
sed -i -e '
  /^# enable bash completion /,/^#fi/!b
  /^# enable bash completion /n
  s/^#//
' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

---

```
perl -pi -e '
  my $e = /^# enable bash completion / ... /^#fi$/m;
  $e =~ /^1?$/ || s/^#//;
' /etc/bash.bashrc
```

Answer (score 0):

```
sed -n -e '
 /^# enable bash completion/{
  h 
  :a {
   n
   /^#fi$/!{
    H 
    ba
   }
  }
  g
  s/#//g
  s/.*/#&\nfi/
 }
 p
' data
```

Save the line in the hold space if we get the `bash completion` section and append each line to the hold space untill we reach the last `fi`. At this point get the content of the hold space and: 1) remove all the `#`, 2) Put a `#` in front of `enable bash completion ...` and append the final `fi` to the block.

Add the `-i` option to let `sed` do changes on the file itself : `sed -n -i -e 'the previous sed command'`